# query for access selective array items from COSMOS db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to fetch some selective array items from following array in cosmos db collection.

"details": [
{

```
            "name": "a",
            "roll_no": 100,
            "sub":"maths",
            "class":"3"
           
        },
        {
           
            "name": "b",
            "roll_no":"512",
            "sub":"eng",
            "class":"5"
           
        },
         {
           
            "name": "c",
            "roll_no":"512",
            "sub":"eng",
            "class":"7"
           
        }
        and so on
```

Desired output is:

"details": [
{

```
            "name": "a",
            "roll_no": 100,
            
           
        },
        {
           
            "name": "b",
            "roll_no":"512",
            
           
        },
         {
           
            "name": "c",
            "roll_no":"512",
            
           
        }
        and so on
```

How can I write query for the same  in cosmosb db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery and the `ARRAY` function will work:

```sql
SELECT c.id, ARRAY(SELECT d.name, d.roll_no FROM d in c.details) AS details
FROM c
```